# No hyphenation for ngerman with Plain-TeX after a recent MiKTeX package update

Tags: hyphenation, plain-tex, miktex2.9, german

German hyphenation worked fine with my MiKTeX installation of February 2019 for Plain TeX input with just ngerman.sty as control sequence. But after I executed a package update on 26 September 2020 I am getting no hyphenation any longer. Because I installed the 134 package updates accumulated since February 2019 offered by default (optional, required and 5 packages removed) I cannot identify the cause. How can I again get Plain TeX with German hyphenation?